# Datastructure Storage in Filesystem 

Tags: c++, c, binary-compatibility

I am trying to write a persistent datastructure in C++ , however I feel that I should be able to make it binary compatible with various other implementations of my datastructure readers, and hence, my current idea is to declare datastructure in the native memory without any abstraction.

For example, I would specify a linear block of memory as a datastructure (using `new` keyword) and then describe what the first byte means, what the second byte means and so on. I know I can do this using `struct` but then, the datastructure would be bound to one language and other languages will have to then use this structure. Also, the implementation might then change from compiler to compiler. I would instead like it as a memory standard.

Is what I am trying to do somewhat sensible? Or I am trying to over-simplify things and should really proceed with a `struct` data structure? Now onto the C++ part, if you believe that I should be using a `struct` data structure, then what are the disadvantages of using a full-fledged class?

(I am using a class anyway to wrap around the memory structure and provide functions to it since the datastructure is anyway persistent.)
**EDIT**
As justin as suggested, I do not *need* any such advanced interface wrapper around the memory structure, so my last point about class wrapper is not stated properly. What I mean is I would like to have a class interface for the memory representation, it does not necessarily have to be a wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several file formats I have read/worked with do exactly that -- define a memory standard or layout, then typically back it up with a demonstration in C-like pseudo-`struct`ure. Sometimes they will provide struct or class representations, and some are completely abstracted by a library. Of course, these formats go on to document all fields, their sizes, the endianness of the data and so on.

I figure endian related issues, padding, complexity (e.g. introduced by variations in the data structures) and proper versioning are the biggest sources of errors. Another issue I find is the use of data structures of yesteryear and inconsistency of data structures used to represent similar functionalities -- You may receive a spec, and realize it contains several different string representations -- all of which are archaic, and somebody has to go on to support all of these (bidirectionally).

Proceeding that route:

You should not commit to a binary representation (or compilable program) if you don't want to support it (and attempts of long-lived formats fail/stumble along the way, as platforms and toolsets change). Just commit to a formal memory standard at first, then build on top of that with tests and example input files to verify the representation is properly serialized and deserialized correctly. A very basic test suite will help ensure your model is portable on all the systems you need, and can point out potential pitfalls or platform specific considerations you may not have been aware of.

If you really want to provide a compilable representation, I'd stick with a very compliant `struct` representation -- clients can take that (in memory) representation and turn it into any C++ abstraction/representation they like. That is to say, a serialized representation should probably not reflect that of a representation in memory, apart from trivially simple representations and the intermediate storage of such a representation (flattened and packed structs).

One of the important parts is that you should have tests which confirm your in memory object graph which you create with these structs are forward and backwards serializable and de-serializable, and support proper versioning -- so it often takes a bit of work to make a complex serialized representation compatible. So you see this approach just introduces one abstraction layer on top of another. In this regard, you may want give C++ abstraction the ability to create itself from the packed in memory representation, and to ensure that that representation can also correctly populate the packed structure without data loss.

Beyond that, is there any *need* to have a more advanced interface? If there is, then you may want to provide that information.

So yes, the memory standard is the part that you must get correct and stable, and to which all implementations should refer to and test against -- regardless of platform/architecture differences. IOW, you're on the right track ;)

Comment: No there isn't any need beyond what you have described to have a more advanced interface.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ there's no practical difference between `struct` and `class` (besides the default accessibility being public in `struct`). Traditionally, `struct` is used when a type only has (public) member variables and no member functions but this is only a convention, not a rule enforced by the compiler.

I'd certainly use a `struct`/`class` to describe the data. If someone wants to write a reader of your data structure, they can either import your header file or implement the data structure in their language of choice - in most programming languages this should be pretty simple.

I recommend you start your structure something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int Version; // struct layout version
    int ByteSize; // byte size of structure for validation
    ...
} MYDATA;
```

This way when your data structure is being passed around, your code can verify that the allocated structure size matches with how many bytes you'd expect for a given version of your structure. You could then easily introduce new versions of your structure by simply updating the version field and checking for the new size.

When you save your data to disk, make sure that you write it out field-by-field, rather than through a single write (using a pointer and `sizeof()` to ensure that other languages won't have to deal with potential padding that your C++ compiler may decide to put in. It's possible to manually lay out fields in the structure so that there's no padding but you have to be very, very careful while doing that and it's easy to make mistakes.